# Suddenly getting "error 53" when mapping drives to SMB shares between Windows 10 systems

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I'm suddenly getting failures when trying to map drives or access shares via UNC on a target system.

The shares cannot be accessed using the network name (\\computername) or IP address (\\192.168...).

To my knowledge, nothing has recently changed or updated with either system.

The "client" can identify the network name of the "server".

Both systems...

- can ping each other
- have been rebooted
- have private network profiles
- have sharing and discovery enabled

For what reasons could this just suddenly happen?

**EDIT**

Turns out there is probably a conflicting device on the network.  Will update with answer once solved.

**EDIT 2**

Confirmed, it was an IP address conflict.

Comment: Is one system trying to connect using login credentials that changed on either system?

Comment: I have had times where it appeared as though the local system was caching something that prevented proper connection to the remote system. I cannot recall exactly, but `nbstat -R` and/or `ipconfig /flushdns` may have helped. The hostnames were the same but there was {magic} stored, assuming invalid or changed data

Comment: Perhaps run  TCP/IP Reset and restart, test.   .....  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: @LPChip: no credentials have changed.

Comment: @John: ran TCP/IP reset, failure persists

Comment: Renew the credential by running Credential Manager and deleting the credentials for the target system, then connect again.

Comment: @harrymc: thanks, I checked the creds manager (and also rebooted, which should clear temporary creds), there's nothing to delete.